# Blazor Server: how to "watch file changes" AND "attach to Visual Studio"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

It looks like I am being forced to chose between the two (either "watch file changes mode" or "attach to Visual Studio mode").

These are the two different "profiles" in `launchSettings.json`, and I have to chose one or the other:

```
"profiles": {
    ...
    "Watch file changes": { 
        "executablePath": "dotnet.exe",
        "workingDirectory": "$(ProjectDir)",
        "commandLineArgs": "watch run debug",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000/",
        "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
    },
    "Attach to VS": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
        "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }           
    }
}
```

It is less than ideal that I have to pick one, I would like to be able to apply a breakpoint ("Attach to VS" mode) *and also* watch file changes.

---

BTW, for those interested: the profile "Watch file changes" must be coordinated with the following addition to your .csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <!-- Files that the "dotnet watch" will monitor for hot reloading: -->
    <Watch Include="**\*.razor" />
    <Watch Include="**\*.scss" />
    <Watch Include="**\*.cshtml"/>
    <Watch Include="**\*.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: In [this article](https://medium.com/@mdhayford/blazor-debug-and-live-reload-85f5ee92a0fa) they propose the user of `browser-sync`:  . Although they presume that `dotnet watch run` can be properly attached to Visual Studio, which is what I am failing to achieve.

Comment: I have found [this interesting project](https://github.com/dazinator/NetPack) that tries to solve the "hot reload" issue (I guess it's named "Netpack" as in "Webpack for dotnet"). I haven't tested it yet. The ["samples project"](https://github.com/dazinator/NetPack.Samples) doesn't work out of the box for me, which is not a good start... but I'll try to dig deeper.

Comment: Were you able to find a way to hot reload and debug in Visual Studio @Xavier ?

Comment: @XavierPeña I belive https://www.livesharp.net/ does what you need. It's commercial. I use it.. it has its qwirks but I can recommend it, because it's really easy to setup.

Answer (score 2):

I am able to debug (breakpoint, step by step, inspect variable) my Blazor Webassembly (Blazor WASM) in Visual Studio 2019. And whenever I save certain files (*.razor, *.razor.cs, *.css), `dotnet` will automatically rebuild the project then Chrome will automatically refresh the page. Here's what I did:

1. In Visual Studio, start debugging (F5) using the "IIS Express" profile. This will open a new Chrome window.
2. Open a command prompt in your project's directory. run `dotnet watch run`. This will open a new Chrome tab.
3. Open the website found in step 2 using the Chrome window in step 1. In other words, copy the URL found in step 2, then paste it to the Chrome address bar found in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

- Right Click on on Main Folder name in the Solution Explorer.
- Go to the "Open Folder in File Explorer".
- In the File Explorer,

  - Type `cmd` in search.
  - `dotnet watch run`

Advantages:

- It will save you a lot of time.
- Automatic reload

Disadvantages:

- There will be no debugger attached.
- There will be no hard reload (not 100% sure).
- In difficult problems, it is better not to use it.